# How to set component sizes based on parent using Swing

Tags: java, swing

Say I have a resizable JFrame *`GUI`*, with size `Dimension(x,y)`. I want to insert objects of class *`JPanelExtender`* into *`GUI`* (preferably using BoxLayout). To keep it simple, let's say each of these objects has a field *`percent`* which is a double between 0.0 and 1.0 and the sum of all `percent`s is 1.

How can I make all of the JPanelExtenders always be exactly of size `Dimension(x*percent, y)`, where x and y are the updated JFrame values after resizes?
I have tried using `setSize(getParent().getHeight(), getParent.getWidth()*percent))` in the `paint(Graphics)` method, and overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method but neither works.
What methods do I have to override? Do I need to use null layout? How does this affect components within my `JPanelExtender`s? 
In general I'm confused about how LayoutManagers allocate space to components, what factors take precedence, and how to control those things myself.

**Note**: I realize this is a very abstract question and SO likes specific examples and code, but I really want to *know* in principle and my actual program requires this kind of thing on multiple panels such that sharing specifics would only obscure the crux of my question. Any references to guides and such (I've already read the Oracle LayoutManager tutorials) would be appreciated.

**Other Note**: It'd be nice if I could use this resizing for components in a GridBagLayout too.

Comment: GridLayout is used to layout components in equally sized cells, that is, all components get same size. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't exactly see how that helps me. If it's unclear, I want unevenly spaced components, in a proportion determined by myself.